# IRC on a web server

Tags: centos, web-server, irc

Would it be reasonable to run an irc server on a webserver? Would there be a lot of impact?

This server will be used for interoffice relations connected to by 12-20 people at a time.

I'm looking at UnrealIRCD + Anope Services

> Dual Quad
>
> HyperThreaded
>
> 12gb ram
>
> 750gb disk space Raid1
>
> 1750gb monthl bandwidth
>
> CentOS

Sever Status:

```
Server load 0.9 (16 CPUs)   
Memory Used 8.79% (1,074,912 of 12,226,188) 
Swap Used   0% (0 of 33,559,768)
```

Apache Status:

```
Current Time: Thursday, 29-Sep-2011 08:53:08 PDT
Restart Time: Tuesday, 13-Sep-2011 13:19:01 PDT
Parent Server Generation: 266
Server uptime: 15 days 19 hours 34 minutes 7 seconds
Total accesses: 10322067 - Total Traffic: 99.2 GB
CPU Usage: u1.34 s.87 cu448.33 cs0 - .033% CPU load
7.55 requests/sec - 76.1 kB/second - 10.1 kB/request
19 requests currently being processed, 10 idle workers
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking unless you're providing service to thousands of very active users, IRC is a very low-load application. That said, you've provided zero details about the current load situation on your server, so none of us is going to be able to give you a good answer.

Other than possible load issues, there's nothing inherent about running and IRCd that would cause negative affects on an httpd.

Comment: ... only the problem of running two services on one machine. So a Webserver exploit can affect IRC. Or vice versa.

Comment: I've edited my question to provide current server load

Comment: @KorvinSzanto With this server you can have thousands of people communicating.